# What chapters contain secret pieces in Carto?

Tags: carto

In Carto, after you complete the game, a new Secrets menu option opens up.  This shows a box with the outline of 6 jigsaw puzzle pieces.  I'm fairly sure

> there's one for each biome, because they're marked with the symbols of each one.

I managed to find one of the secret pieces in chapter 8-2.  What other chapters do I need to look in?

At this point, I just want a list of chapter numbers.  Any additional hints should be marked as spoilers, please.

Answer (score 2):

There are secret pieces in Chapters 2, 5, 6-2, 7, 8-2 and 9.

Below are additional hints to find them: In order, they give the achievement name associated with the piece, the achievement description, and finally direct instructions on how to get the piece. Information was from [the Carto Wiki](https://carto.fandom.com/wiki/Secret_Piece) and [Half-Glass Gaming](https://halfglassgaming.com/2020/10/carto-home-sweet-home-trophy-how-to-visit-the-airship/).

#### Secret Piece I

> Chapter 8-2

Achievement Name

> Strange Catch

Achievement Description

> Find something mysterious in the lake.

Instructions:

> During the fishing tournament, find the small fish drawn by a child with a stick. Create that lake shape with one head piece and one tail piece. Fish in the lake and catch the fish.

#### Secret Piece II

> Chapter 2

Achievement Name

> Ground of Applause

Achievement Description

> Give a plant your full support.

Instructions

> After waking up to catch the Ghost Lilly, go to the hut surrounded by yellow-bulbed plants and find a potted plant. Interact with it 5 times to make a flower bloom.

#### Secret Piece III

> Chapter 6-2

Achievement Name

> Cawtet

Achievement Description

> Listen to the quartet of birds.

Instructions

> There are 4 bright blue birds on the corners of specific tiles. Each tile has paths. One has a dead end with a fireplace, one is a T intersection with water, one is a curved corner path, and one is a standard dead end. Arrange the tiles so the 4 birds are close to each other and inspect the birds.

#### Secret Piece IV

> Chapter 5

Achievement Name

> Not So Sharp

Achievement Description

> Learn nothing about cactuses.

Instructions

> Find a cactus and interact with it 5 times.

#### Secret Piece V

> Chapter 7

Achievement Name

> Stirring Things Up

Achievement Description

> Behold the legendary flame tornado!

Instructions

> After you make the volcano erupt, climb a later to the surface. Open the map and rapidly rotate the volcano tile until it forms a flame tornado.

#### Secret Piece VI

> Chapter 9

Achievement Name

> Frosty Friend

Achievement Description

> Finish snowman buddy.

Instructions

> There are 4 parts of a snowman you need to find: body, head, arms, and hat. The head, arms, and body can be found on the square iceberg just outside the 3 surrounding wooden gates. The hat requires solving a sliding puzzle. (Refer to [the Carto wiki's visual guide](https://carto.fandom.com/wiki/Secret_Piece#Secret_Piece_VI) or [this video by Lightgun Galaxy](https://youtu.be/czQR7hT1CNM?t=339))